# Apache and systemd

Tags: debian, systemd, apache-httpd

I've just started using Debian 8 which has introduced systemd. I'm not interested in the politics around SysV vs systemd, but I am confused, especially around Apache (2.4).

There are now two ways to restart apache:

1. `apache2ctl restart` or `apache2ctl graceful`
2. `systemctl restart apache2` and it seems `systemctl restart apache2.service` does the same thing.

And they appear to do different things(!). I don't understand the difference.

I seem to need to do both to get a proper full restart working. e.g. after changing a config file for the php module it only noted the change after both.

Another time when `apache2ctl configtest` was failing and the failure was reported in `systemctl status apache2` I fixed the config so that the first of these commands was happy, restarted with `apache2ctl restart` but the systemd status command still listed it as not running and with the old config problem.

I promise to spend ages reading about systemd (RTFM) in depth at some point, but meanwhile on a practical level relating to apache, I'd appreciate advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want consistency, always use `systemctl` for `stop`, `start`, and `restart`.  That ends up using the `apache2ctl` program - for now via the `/etc/init.d/apache2` script but probably from a native `systemd` unit file in the future.

`systemd` won't know when you've used `apache2ctl` directly, possibly resulting (as you've discovered) in a situation where `systemd` thinks `apache2` is still in a faulty state when it's actually running fine.

For `configtest` and `status`, use `apache2ctl`.  They just query apache without changing its state.

Comment: So systemctl status doesn't use apache2ctl?

Comment: `systemctl status apache2` tells you if the service is running.  `apache2ctl status` gives you the output from `mod_status` if it is enabled and configured.